# NVIDIA Display Settings Wiped on Reboot Ubuntu 12.10 64bit

Tags: 12.10, nvidia, xorg, 64-bit, display

I have the latest (31X beta) NVIDIA drivers on Ubuntu 12.10 64bit and no matter how many times I save my display configuration settings after editing my refresh rate and dual monitor position the settings revert back to default every time I reboot or log out & log in.

After looking extensively into the issue I learned that NVIDIA by default loads different display settings based on the user logged in. I know this is true because on the login screen it displays 120hz, but the moment I log in to my account the settings are reverted.

My issue is I can not for the life of me figure out how to save my display configuration on a user level instead of system wide. I have tried starting the NVIDIA settings pane as root to change settings but that still only saves settings system wide.

Any help would be much appreciated! Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Press Crtl-Alt-t. In terminal run.

```
sudo mv -i /etc/X11/xorg.conf /etc/X11/xorg.conf.backup
sudo touch /etc/X11/xorg.conf
gksu nvidia-settings
```

(when you're prompted for your password, and you type it in there is no feedback, don't worry that's normal)

create all your settings. When you're done click the "save configuration" option

---

Please try [this workaround](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2053501#td_post_12220900),  just change `nvidia-current` to `nvidia-experimental-310`

Comment: This didn't seem to help the issue unfortunately.